# Are there any audited webbrowsers in OpenBSD?

Tags: openbsd

I'm looking for an [audited](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23558/what-audited-server-programs-are-shipped-in-a-default-openbsd-install) web browser on OpenBSD. As far as I can tell nothing in Ports is audited, so are there any browsers built-in on OpenBSD?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To quote the [OpenBSD FAQ](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/index.html) on [What web browsers are available](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq8.html#Browsers):

> [Lynx](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=lynx&sektion=1), a text-based browser, is in the base system, and has SSL support. Other browsers in the ports tree...

Answer (score 4):

XXXTerm is developed by Marco Peereboom an OpenBSD developer, probably as good as you'll find for graphical browsers security wise in the ports https://opensource.conformal.com/wiki/xxxterm

Comment: "In early 2017, it appeared the project was likely to be discontinued, as xombrero depended on an old version of WebKit which had multiple security vulnerabilities, and a port to a modern version of WebKit would be difficult. Due to these issues,[3] OpenBSD removed xombrero from its ports tree on 1 February 2017."

Answer (score 3):

The answer is 'No'. While Lynx used to be part of the Base Installation, it was removed because of support for 'ancient protocols' bibp, finger, gopher, and news.

You can install it from ports/packages, but there is no web browser actually built-in to the base installation any longer.