# What audited server programs are shipped in a default OpenBSD install?

Tags: openbsd

OpenBSD has a process by which they [audit programs](http://www.openbsd.org/security.html) by doing a "comprehensive file-by-file analysis of every critical software component". Which OpenBSD programs have been audited? Is there a list? I know `httpd`, `ftpd`, and `sshd` have been audited, but I can't find a comprehensive list

Comment: why do you think that openbsd software is 'audited'? What do you mean by 'audited' ?

Comment: http://www.openbsd.org/security.html - Audit Process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May [the](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/libexec/) [source](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.sbin/) be with you.